# InApp Purchase, SKProduct Problems with localized Properties

Tags: iphone, localized

I have implemented an InApp Purchase Store in my app. I have English and German as languages. But I always get the German titles and descriptions from the SKProducts. I am calling the right localizedDescription localizedTitle methods, so this should be not the problem, according to the documentation.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

App Store seems to return localized strings based on user country, rather than user-selected language in Settings.app. In other words, if you shop in the German store, you will get German localized strings from App Store.

Answer (score 2):

Tried with the language setting in the setting and it didn't work for SKProduct's localizedTitle (still display the english product title).
In order to change the country for App Store, I had to go to iTunes on my phone, log out my current account. select create a new apple ID -> select country -> next. Then relaunch app store to verify it's a different country.
PS grobald, Thank you so much for the hint!